# How to set parameters in nested query in DQL

Tags: symfony, parameters, doctrine, nested, subquery

**Hi**,
I'd like to get number of created articles by a user, the query used to work until I added some parameters filtering the query by "fromDate" and "toDate" dates, here's my query :

```
// query String
$dql = 'SELECT u.idUser,
               u.lastName,
               u.email,
               u.mobile,
               (SELECT AVG(n.note)
                FROM MyBundle:Note n
                WHERE n.noteFor = u.idUser) AS note,
               (SELECT COUNT(a) 
                FROM MyBundle:Article a 
                WHERE (a.createdBy = u.idUser) AND (a.createdAt BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate)) AS articles
         FROM MyBundle:User u';

// create the actual query
$users= $em->createQuery($dql);
// set filter date parameter
$users->setParameter('fromDate', $fromDate.'00:00:00');
$users->setParameter('toDate', $toDate.'23:59:59');
```

I keep getting this error : `Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens.`
I tried searching in the doctrine documentation for how to set parameters in nested queries without finding anything. first I need to know if it's possible to do that then find where the error come from,  **Please Help !**

Comment: i suggest you to build the nested query with the query builder then add to the main query. Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks Matteo, I really like working with queries like this instead of query builder, I Think I found another solution to do the same query, I'll post it when I finish testing it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after performing some tests, I found out that the query worked well the way it was and the problem wasn't there.
I'm using [KnpPaginatorBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle) to paginate my queries, it seems that the problem was that it couldn't paginate complex queries like passing multiple parameters in the nested query. so I found a solution.
 So this is the **old code** :

```
// Pagination
$paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
$users     = $paginator->paginate($users, 1, 10);
```

And this is the **new code** :

```
// Pagination
$paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
$users     = $paginator->paginate($users, 1, 10, array('wrap-queries' => true) );
```

Thanks to Nisam and Matteo for their time, hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Use `setParameters()` instead of `setParameter()`

```
$users->setParameters(array('fromDate'=> $fromDate.'00:00:00','toDate'=> $toDate.'23:59:59'))
```

Comment: Thanks Nisam for the quick reply, I already tried that, it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Look at this documents: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html?highlight=createQuery

Comment: Yep, that's the documentation I was reading, I'd like to know if it's possible at first, if doctrine allows setting parameters in nested queries because it seems as though the "fromDate" and "toDate" in the nested query aren't considered at all, and thanks again for everything, much appreciated